# Why don't I see the minhag to put grass in shul?

Tags: minhag, ashkenazi, shavuos

The Rema [brings](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.494.3) a minhag to put grass and other herbage in shul for Shavuos. I've seen this practiced only once. Why don't more Ashkenazi shuls follow this minhag?

I feel some would be tempted to say that the Gra annulled this minhag, as [brought](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.494.10) in that Simman by the Mishnah Berurah. But if you look carefully, he's discussing a different minhag: to put trees in shul. That minhag was [brought](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.494.5) by the Magen Avraham, not the Rema.

Comment: My shul follows this minhag. Maybe we’ve seen each other before, and my shul is the one where you’ve seen this? :)

Comment: Ultimately, since this is a minhag, it could just depend on community preference. Some communities think it’s a good thing, others think not. It’s not like it’s an actual Halacha which must be followed.

Comment: I've seen this done in most synagogues that I've been in on _Shavuos_, fwiw.

Comment: @donielf - your shul literally has grass or other flowers? OP asked about grass

Comment: @Draizy-LeviPine The wording of the Rema, עשבים, doesn’t always refer to grass. Sometimes it means weeds. Sometimes it means flowers. It really just refers to things which grow from the ground.

Comment: Our shul has plants and flowers - not on the floor though - probably not very practical

Comment: I think the grass was put on the floors - when they were unpaved_. Not relevant nowadays. AFAIK shuls that don't put trees put up some flower arrangements. .

Comment: See image of the decorated Yekke-Shul "Kehillas Askenaz" in Kiryat-Sefer HERE: https://www.kikar.co.il/%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%94%D7%97%D7%92-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%99%D7%91-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%95.html

Comment: It's not true that the Gra prohibited trees specifically (though it's a common misconception nowadays, I grant you). The Gra is your answer

Comment: @DoubleAA there is no Beur Hagra there, so all I have is the MB's statement that he anulled trees. Where is the source?

Comment: You're being medayek in the Mishna Berura but he's just quoting the Chayei Adam who doesn't ever mention grass to need to reject it. Probably people had shifted to sturdier greenery as their floors became not earth and their standards of cleanliness precluded strewn grass. Or are you also asking about flowers?

Comment: @DoubleAA whatever עשבים includes. I haven't seen either. Maybe because I mostly daven in yeshivos, which seem to not follow this minhag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your thought, that the Vilna Gaon only prohibited trees, has become popular recently with the [popularization of Christmas trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_tree#18th_to_early_20th_centuries), it's not historically accurate. He prohibited greenery on Shavuot because it paralleled the greenery set up in churches (especially Orthodox ones) for [Pentecost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentecost) (the Christian holiday which parallels Shavuot) which commonly includes birch branches and red flowers. This is noted explicitly in his student's *Chayei Adam* (131:13):

> והגר״א ביטל מנהג מלהעמיד אילנות בעצרת משום שעכשיו הוא חק העמים להעמיד .אילנות בחג שלהם שקורין זאלאני״ע או פינגסט״ן‏
>   And the GR"A nullified the custom to put up trees on Shavuot because now it's the practice of the nations to put up trees on their holiday that they call [Zelelnia](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zes%C5%82anie_Ducha_%C5%9Awi%C4%99tego) or [Pfingsten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfingsten).

That's all the Chayei Adam wrote. He never mentioned a custom about "grasses" beforehand that you can learn that he meant "trees" specifically and not "greenery", nor would such a read make sense since churches on Pentecost don't exclusively use trees. Indeed another of the Vilna Gaon's students, R' Mordechai ben [Aryeh Leib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Leib_Epstein), wrote (Sefer HaLikuttim):

> מנהגו של החסיד שביטל העשבים בשבועות אף שהרמ״א הביאו...‏
>   The custom of [the Vilna Gaon] who nullified the grasses on Shavuot even though the Rama brought it.

Igrot Moshe ([YD 4:11:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=214)) also understands the Chayei Adam and Vilna Gaon to be referring to both "trees" and "grasses" because of Pentecost.

The Arukh haShulchan, after writing about the old customs of both "grasses" and "trees", concludes:

> אמנם בדורות שלפנינו ביטלו האילנות והעשבים, מטעמים שידעו הגדולים שבדור.‏
>   However, in the generations that preceded us they nullified the [customs of] trees and grasses [because of the Vilna Gaon].

The Arukh haShulchan's assessment of common practice matches yours.

(I note though the custom is still alive and well in some communities.)

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2017/05/

Comment: Fwiw the Dirshu MB says the Steipler and Rav Shlomo Zalman say the Gra doesn't apply to עשבים, but they bring the Igros Moshe and Aruch HaShulchan that you brought that it does. They add that despite his view, the Steipler (along with the Chazon Ish) intentionally set up the minhag in charedi communities in EY not to spread out עשבים.

Comment: @robev I told you it was popular recently :)

Comment: The Chayei Adam as I see it writes "זאלאניא שווענטע", but you left out the second word. What is that second word? Also you spelled the first word with a ע; not sure it matters.

Comment: @robev Alas I left no record of where I copied the text from so I don't know why the differences. I don't think it matters for the main thesis though. See the wikipedia link which calls the holiday Zesłanie Ducha Świętego where Świętego is probably the cognate of שווענטע. But I don't speak Polish or Yiddish so you should probably ask someone else.